# Is it possible to chainload a disk-image file from Grub?

Tags: grub

I have a disk image that is meant to be flashed and run as a live-USB. Is it possible to boot from this image in Grub in a similar way to booting from an ISO?

Comment: Welcome! What kind of image is it?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?